# Absorbing regions in Physics

Tags: potential, computational-physics, simulations, hawking-radiation, bose-einstein-condensate

How would you define an absorbing region (at the walls of a finite numerical simulation) in physics and how would you implement it?
Can it be simulated by a high potential, low negative potential at the boundaries, how?

Or an imaginary (damping) potential? It has to do with this sentence if found in [arXiv:083.0507](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0507) (last paragraph of page 5):

> ...but an absorbing region far from the horizon is required to prevent the onset of spurious dynamical instabilities due to excitations circulating around the integration box.

Comment: @KyleKanos: as you are interested in this problem, please answer it

Comment: My experience in Comp-Phys is with fluid dynamics, not QM; in that case, absorbing BCs are usually $\partial_xu=0$. Whether that holds for the GPE the authors are intending to solve, I do not know.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I mean with potentials. High potentials at the edges mean reflecting walls. And so forth... Could you maybe upvote this question such that it gets an answer faster. This is a bit in general not only QM

Comment: In quantum mechanics an imaginary part in the potential corresponds to decay that's possible in that region. Note, that this makes the time evolution non-unitary (and this is correct, the probability of finding the particle anywhere goes down with time!). It can be understood as an approximation for weak coupling to a many mode environment and tracing the environment out. A perfectly absorbing wall is, however, more difficult (just cranking the absorption up will lead to reflection).

Comment: @SebastianRiese: how would you do it than for this problem, numerically (e.g., in a computer program)? How would you change the potential?

Comment: Well in a computer program you can just set the potential to a imaginary number in some area – nothing stops you. Then in that area the particle decays with a rate related to the imaginary part of the potential. You just have to be careful when connecting it to a physical system.